# Пути обоих звезд

Tags: собирательные-числительные

Ошибка (*обоих* звезд) может быть допущена осознанно? Статья-то вполне на уровне, чтобы предполагать в ней даже опечатку.

> ... не Ален Делон, а именно Бельмондо. Первый был слишком красив,
> слишком высокомерен и, кажется, обижен на весь мир. А Жан-Поль — это
> сама легкость, беззаботность, незлобивость... Хотя пути обоих звезд в
> кино в чем-то схожи.

Comment: Зачем вам отвечать, если вы не ставите галочки? Вам угодить невозможно!

Comment: Отчего же? Иногда и две-три хочется, да не можется. Как Галочке, к примеру.

Comment: 24 последних вопроса без галочки. Последняя была 2 года назад. У вас 110 вопросов и всего лишь 6 принятых ответов.

Comment: Если не трудно (похоже, что шашечки вам дороги), посчитайте все. А я продолжу доносить мысли более словами, и менее — жестами.

Answer (score 1):

Ой как мне нравятся ОБЫГРАННЫЕ КОНТЕКСТОМ обои звезды!

Но нет же ж: Справка Грамоты.ру изволит [возражать](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=302643):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но - остаётся право не верить конкретному отвечателю (мало ли их по Справке бродит, а потом сайт извинения приносит).

Автор не опечатался. Просто не захотел, чтобы его мальчик-звезда училась.

Comment: Спасибо, Galina! Ошибка или оплошность: сдаётся мне, что автор забыл удалить одно из этих слов, отложив выбор на потом.